# Store robbery algorithm - fill robbery bag with best price and weight ratio to maximum capacity

Tags: typescript, algorithm

In some job interview, I have been asked with this question.

You are robbing a store, and you have a bag with **X** maximum capacity volume (weight).
The store has products, each product has a `price` and `volume`.

Make an algorithm / equation that fills up your robbery bag:

1. Fill the bag with the best price SUM you can get based on the weight.
2. Make it with the best complexity you can think of.

I thought of one way that might be wrong, I will be using typescript to explain my answer:

First of all I will declare the `Product` interface:

```
interface Product {
    // The price of the product in the store
    price: number;

    // The weight of the product
    volume: number;
}
```

Secondary, I will be creating an inheritance of `Product` because I am going to be calculating the ratio that I will explain later:

```
interface RatedProduct extends Product {
    // price divided by weight
    ratio: number;
}
```

My idea is to loop through all product elements and divide `price` by `weight` to create price to weight ratio.

This is my initial data I set:

```
const products: Product[] = [
    {
        price: 5,
        volume: 10
    },
    {
        price: 10,
        volume: 10
    },
    {
        price: 5,
        volume: 5
    },
    {
        price: 6,
        volume: 2
    },
    {
        price: 5,
        volume: 14
    },
    {
        price: 1,
        volume: 1
    },
    {
        price: 2,
        volume: 2
    },
    {
        price: 7,
        volume: 9
    },
];
```

And this is the products with ratio array:

```
const ratedProducts: RatedProduct[] = [];
```

Here I create an array of products with a set ratio which I will be working with:

```
// Create array of rated products
products.forEach(product => {
   ratedProducts.push(
       {
           price: product.price,
           volume: product.volume,
           ratio: product.price / product.volume,
       }
   )
});
```

Sort the array by `ratio` **and** `price`:

```
ratedProducts.sort((a, b) => {
   return b.ratio - a.ratio || b.price - a.price;
});
```

Now I have a sorted array:

```
[ { price: 6, volume: 2, ratio: 3 },
  { price: 10, volume: 10, ratio: 1 },
  { price: 5, volume: 5, ratio: 1 },
  { price: 2, volume: 2, ratio: 1 },
  { price: 1, volume: 1, ratio: 1 },
  { price: 7, volume: 9, ratio: 0.7777777777777778 },
  { price: 5, volume: 10, ratio: 0.5 },
  { price: 5, volume: 14, ratio: 0.35714285714285715 } ]
```

Now I can insert items from index 0 and on till I fill my bag's max capacity which is a set constant:

```
const maxCapacity: number = 10; // 10kg
```

I may be miss-understanding the question, I am not too sure if this is a correct answer, is this the right approach, am I missing something?

Comment: This is the knapsack problem: you can solve this in pseudo-polynomial time with dynamic programming.

Comment: The ratio is not sufficient. By using a greedy approach, you are, iirc guaranteed to be s close as halfway compared to the optimum, but not per se the optimum.

Comment: Consider what happens when `maxCapacity` is `28`; your method will grab the `{price: 1, volume: 1}` product when it would be better to leave it and grab the `{price: 7, volume: 9}` product. I'd be inclined to write a recursive solution that exits whenever it can't fit any remaining items or if it can fit *all* remaining items, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/4ls41).  There are ways to possibly improve by caching partial results, but ‍♂️.  Also, see [0-1 knapsack problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/)